# The array literal notation [] is preferrable

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm reading this article and I'm not understanding it.

http://linterrors.com/js/the-array-literal-notation-is-preferrable

It then says: "This error is raised to highlight a potentially dangerous and unnecessarily verbose piece of code."

I don't get it. If I would be overriding the constructor, it would be me doing the overriding, so how is this a dangerous thing?

Comment: Someone else might override it, in a piece of code that you've imported as part of a library.

Comment: Also, `new Array` is inconsistent in its behavior which can lead to bugs - imagine a piece of code like `new Array(123, ...otherArray)`. If `otherArray` was an array like `[456, 789]` then it would create an array `[123, 456, 789]`. But if `otherArray` was an empty array, it would instead create an array with 123 empty elements inside! But the code `[123, ...otherArray]` would instead yield `[123]` which is probably what was desired.